# Use VBA to Fill Textbox and Click Button on Webpage

Tags: java, html, vba, dom

I'm trying to use VBA to excess a webpage. What I want to do is to fill a textbox with my own inputs and then proceed to the search result by pressing the search button.

Here's the link of the webpage: http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

On the right side of the page, under "Fast Search", there is a box that I can put in a stock ticker or a CIK code, and if I type in "AAPL" and click the "search" button right by the textbox, I will be able to see some information regarding the company Apple.

Here's the code I've written:

```
Option Explicit
Const url = "http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html"

Sub Test2()
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate url

Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4
  DoEvents
Loop
ie.Visible = True

With ie.Document
  .GetElementById("cik").Value = "AAPL"
  .GetElementById("search_button_2").Click
End With
End Sub
```

Using it I am able to put "AAPL" into the textbox. But when I run the code, IE will direct me to an error page, telling me it's unable to recognize the ticker I put in. I am fairly certain the ID for the search button is "search_button_2". However I am fairly new to HTML, so I am kind of stuck at the last step.

Thank you guys so much for helping me out. I'd appreciate any solution or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For the First HTML Button, next to the "Company Name" field, the HTML is:

<input id="search_button_1" name="Find" type="submit" value="Search" class="primary">

Therefore, to trigger this button by GetElementById("search_button_1").Click would work.

However, for the Second HTML Button, next to the Fast Search field, the HTML is:

<input name="Find" type="submit" value="Search" class="primary">

On this button there is no "ID", it is therefore not possible to address it in this way.